# sleep in = ausschlafen?

Tags: meaning, english-to-german, difference

Can "ausschlafen" mean "[to sleep in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sleep-in)" (i.e. to sleep until later in the morning than you usually do)?

[Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/ende/sleep%20in) and [DeepL translator](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#en/de/I%20will%20sleep%20in%20on%20Sunday.) say so, but I don't see that meaning in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausschlafen) or [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ausschlafen).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ausschlafen* really means 'to sleep until you're not tired anymore' as defined by Duden and DWDS. Since this requires a certain amount of tiredness, *ausschlafen* implies *sleeping **longer*** than in the nights the tiredness arose from, but **not necessarily** *getting up **later*** than usual. For people of the 'lark' chronotype, e.g., it might mean going to bed early. Accordingly, *ausgeschlafen* means 'well-rested' and not 'having slept late'. Thus, *to sleep in* and *ausschlafen* are probably not entirely equivalent.

Most people, however, would arguably associate *ausschlafen* with getting up late, so *ausschlafen* can indeed (and often does) mean getting up later than usual.

Comment: I'd like to add, that in both cases, sleep in and ausschlafen you are probably not setting an alarm clock, implying sleep as long as you can.

Comment: The proper translation of *to sleep in* in the sense of "not waking up on time" is *verschlafen* (intransitive). E. g. *Ich kam zu spät zur Arbeit, weil ich verschlafen habe".

Comment: Oh, ich kannte "Sleep In" bislang nur von John Lennon und Yoko Ono und hielt es für eine politische Protestform, ähnlich wie ein Teach In oder Sit In - wahrscheinlich ist aber meine Vorstellung zu letzteren Beiden auf analoge Weise falsch.

Comment: @RHa I'd say the proper translation of *verschlafen* is *to oversleep*, but that wasn't asked here.